# How do I setup JSON Text Editor Tabs/Spaces settings in Visual Studio Pro 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I remember in previous versions of VS Pro that I used there used to be a configuration in: `Options -> Text Editor -> JSON -> Tabs` to specify what indentation I need for JSON files. I am currently using VS 2019 and I don't see an item for `JSON` under `Text Editor`. Did the procedure for setting up JSON indentation change? Am I looking in the wrong place? Did I forget to install something?

Answer (score 2):

Create a `.editorconfig` file in the base of your project and enable overriding of config in VS settings:

```
root = true

[*]
insert_final_newline = true
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
indent_style = space

[*.cs]
indent_size = 4

[*.{ps1,xml,json}]
indent_size = 2
```